Got a frequent crash from webkit in our online app on iOS 15 and 16
On our online app, we have a frequent crash on iOS 15 and 16. I googled but found nothing valuable to solve this. The crash info is below:
出错堆栈
0   WebKit
0x00000001d78e4000 + 6795272
1   WebKit
0x00000001d78e4000 + 6795232
2   WebCore
WebCore::ScrollingTreeScrollingNode::wasScrolledByDelegatedScrolling(WebCore::FloatPoint const&, std::__1::optional<WebCore::FloatRect>, WebCore::ScrollingLayerPositionAction) + 328
3   WebKit
0x00000001d78e4000 + 4676228
4   WebKit
0x00000001d78e4000 + 61972
5   UIKitCore
-[UIScrollView _notifyDidScroll] + 72
6   UIKitCore
-[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 1032
7   UIKitCore
-[UIScrollViewScrollAnimation setProgress:] + 276
8   UIKitCore
-[UIAnimator _advanceAnimationsOnScreenWithIdentifier:withTimestamp:] + 184
9   QuartzCore
0x00000001c620f000 + 167868
10  QuartzCore
0x00000001c620f000 + 233316
11  CoreFoundation
___CFMachPortPerform + 176
12  CoreFoundation
___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 60
13  CoreFoundation
___CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 520
14  CoreFoundation
___CFRunLoopRun + 2240
15  CoreFoundation
_CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
16  GraphicsServices
_GSEventRunModal + 164
17  UIKitCore
-[UIApplication _run] + 888
18  UIKitCore
_UIApplicationMain + 340
19  libswiftUIKit.dylib
UIKit.UIApplicationMain(Swift.Int32, Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Int8>>?, Swift.String?, Swift.String?) -> Swift.Int32 + 104

Does anyone know about this? Is this a system bug on iOS? This never happens on iOS 17 or on the latest iOS 18.
